# How fix Error of error of crt1.o,crti.o in Build TinyCCompiler(TCC) from Source?

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, crt, tcc

How fix Error of crt1.o,crti.o in Build TinyCCompiler(TCC) from Source?

https://github.com/LuaDist/tcc

i'm test this at my Desktop system(ubuntu) and also test on server(centos).
at both OS , show error.

### Error :

```
tcc: file '/usr/lib/crt1.o' not found
tcc: file '/usr/lib/crti.o' not found
```

### Details :

guest@Base:~/Gits/tcc-compiler$ ./configure --prefix=build

```
Binary  directory   build/bin
TinyCC directory    build/lib/tcc
Library directory   build/lib
Include directory   build/include
Manual directory    build/man
Doc directory       build/share/doc/tcc
Target root prefix  
Source path      /home/guest/Gits/tcc-compiler
C compiler       gcc
CPU              x86-64
Big Endian       no
gprof enabled    no
cross compilers  no
use libgcc       no
Creating config.mak and config.h
config.h is unchanged
```

guest@Base:~/Gits/tcc-compiler$ sudo make

```
....
....
```

guest@Base:~/Gits/tcc-compiler$ sudo make install

```
mkdir -p "build/bin"
install -s -m755 tcc "build/bin"
mkdir -p "build/man/man1"
install tcc.1 "build/man/man1"
mkdir -p "build/lib/tcc"
mkdir -p "build/lib/tcc/include"
install -m644 libtcc1.a "build/lib/tcc"
install -m644 include/stdarg.h include/stddef.h include/stdbool.h include/float.h include/varargs.h include/tcclib.h "build/lib/tcc/include"
mkdir -p "build/share/doc/tcc"
install -m644 tcc-doc.html "build/share/doc/tcc"
mkdir -p "build/lib"
install -m644 libtcc.a "build/lib"
mkdir -p "build/include"
install -m644 libtcc.h "build/include"
```

guest@Base:~/Gits/tcc-compiler$ cat test2.c

```
#include <tcclib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### Error :

guest@Base:~/Gits/tcc-compiler$ build/bin/tcc test2.c

```
tcc: file '/usr/lib/crt1.o' not found
tcc: file '/usr/lib/crti.o' not found
```

$ find /usr/ -name crti*

```
/usr/mipsel-linux-gnu/lib/crti.o
/usr/lib32/crti.o
/usr/libx32/crti.o
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
```

$ find /usr/ -name crt1*

```
/usr/mipsel-linux-gnu/lib/crt1.o
/usr/lib32/crt1.o
/usr/libx32/crt1.o
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crt1.o
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crt1u.o
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/crt1.o
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/crt1u.o
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
```

(Full Commands available at https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/26211506/)

how can fix error?

---

i'm can install tcc using `sudo apt install tcc`.(without bug and error)

but i want install tcc from source.(this have error)

---

### New Update

in tcc.h file :

```
#define CONFIG_TCC_CRT_PREFIX CONFIG_SYSROOT "/usr/lib"
```

i'm change `/usr/lib` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

$ build/bin/tcc test.c -run

```
Hello World
```

### $ /build/bin/tcc test.c

```
tcc: undefined symbol '__libc_csu_fini'
tcc: undefined symbol '__libc_csu_init'
tcc: undefined symbol '__libc_start_main'
tcc: undefined symbol 'printf'
```

---

### New Update

```
#include <tcclib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### guest@Base:~/Gits/tcc-try/_build/_install/bin$ ./tcc test.c

```
test.c:1: include file 'tcclib.h' not found
```

### How fix error of include files not found?!

Related Question : [How fix Error of error of include files in TinyCCompiler(TCC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955996/how-fix-error-of-error-of-include-files-in-tinyccompilertcc)

Comment: This looks like something you should be asking of the maintainers of the program you are trying to build.

Comment: i not have access to them.  available `tcc` tag at stackoverflow. @ChristianGibbons

Comment: https://github.com/LuaDist/tcc , github not have `issues`!

Comment: Just because we have a [tcc] tag does not mean that all questions about `tcc` are on-topic here.  Sorry.  But you have a source distribution; very likely it contains information about how to contact the maintainers.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like a configuration / installation problem to me.

Comment: not installed for you also? @JohnBollinger

Comment: i think should change `#define CONFIG_TCC_CRT_PREFIX CONFIG_SYSROOT "/usr/lib"` at `tcc.h` file.

Comment: i'm changed to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` , and now new errors.(question text updated)

Comment: my system also is AMD64. @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 1):

The LuaDist project aims to build a complete Lua ecosystem using CMake. So you should use the CMake build system instead of the original makefiles. Typically you would do the following CMake invocation.

```
$ mkdir _build && cd _build
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=_install
$ cmake --build . --target install
```

After this you should have working tcc in _install/bin

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}` , $ ./tcc ../test.c 
`../test.c:1: include file 'stdlib.h' not found`

Comment: `#include <tcclib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}`  $ ./tcc ../test.c  `../test.c:1: include file 'tcclib.h' not found` @drahosp

Comment: How fix error of include files not found?! @drahosp

Comment: @C-Compiler: Stop that flood. Single notion about your question is sufficient. If the answerer wants to see it, he will do that. But do not insist on that.

Comment: Ok sorry, but But I need a small-tiny compiler for C.. @Tsyvarev

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is not exactly an answer to a question, but initially I had the same problem and this is my solution (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
git clone https://github.com/TinyCC/tinycc
cd tinycc
./configure
make
make test
cd ..
echo '#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 printf("Hi!\n");
}' > a.c
tinycc/tcc -Btinycc a.c -o a.o
./a.o
```